# Targeting a div id in javascript with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'll get right into it, kind of a newbie here.

I have a slideshow running on jQuery that also holds text based content in it as well (we'll call this slider "main slider"). When you slide through, the content changes (obviously). What I'm trying to do is put another smaller slider we'll call this "secondary slider" into one of the larger slides on main slider to showcase some photographic content.

I'm having issues.

I can get the secondary slider to work on the same page as the main slider but I'm encountering issues when I "embed" it into the main slider. I'm sure it has something to do with the way the plugin is targeting the div. Here is the markup:

```
<div id="img4" class="ctnsec">
    <div class="slidecontent">
        <div class="graphicleft">
            <ul>
                <li style="float:left;line-height:55px;">
                    <p class="topcopy">GRAPHIC DESIGN</p>
                </li>
                <li style="float:left;padding-left:100px;line-height:38px;">
                    <p class="botcopy">SEE THE DIFFERENCE</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearme"></div>
            <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <!--graphicleft-->
        <div id="banner-slide">
            <ul class="bjqs">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/logos/crust.png" alt="under the crust" title="under the crust" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/logos/space_la.png" alt="space la" title="space la" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/logos/black_cat.png" alt="the black cat" title="the black cat" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/logos/sia.png" alt="social investment advocates" title="social investment advocates" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--banner-slide-->
    </div>
    <!--slidecontent-->
</div>
<!--img4-->
```

And here is the plugin javascript that gets included on the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype: 'slide',
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        responsive: true,
        randomstart: true
    });

});
```

Alright, so you see how the plugin is targeting the div id of "banner-slide" with a class of "bjqs? I need to know how I can tell the plugin that I need to target those same things BUT within the div id of "img4". Is there an easy way of going about this?

Thanks in advance for the help, I really appreciate it!

-Patrick

Comment: Please format your code properly, there is no need for all those spaces on the left hand side (scrolling horizontally is bad).

Comment: *"I need to know how I can tell the plugin that I need to target those same things BUT within the div id of "img4"."* Does this mean you have multiple elements with the same ID? IDs must be unique!

Comment: No, I understand that id's must be unique. I'm only using it in that one spot. I was just having an issue of the plugin not being able to identify the location since it was inside a parent div.

Comment: But I now realize that that doesn't matter. Not sure what I can do now. I need a solution for putting a slider within a slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `<div id="banner-slide">` elements, that's invalid HTML, since IDs must be unique. You should use a class instead, `<div class="banner-slide">`.

Then you can target it with:

```
$("#img4 .banner-slide .bjqs").bxSlider( { ... });
```

The name of the method is `.bxSlider()`, not `.bjqs` -- you seem to be confusing the use of `.` to indicate classes in CSS selectors and also to invoke methods in Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin, I thought he was just having trouble constructing the selector.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Barmar but it seems that I have a bigger issue then. I need to find a solution for putting a slider within a slider. The plugin for the slider works on the same page when not embedded within the "main slider" so I'm not sure what my options are at this point...

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
$('#img4 #banner-slide').bjqs({
    animtype: 'slide',
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
    responsive: true,
    randomstart: true
});
```

Having said that, you're using an ID for banner-side, so using a child selector doesn't really make sense since there can only be one banner-slide.

Comment: I see, so I seem to have a larger issue then. I tried both answers and neither of them worked. It must be an issue with putting a slider within a slider. I wonder if there is a solution to this...